# .htaccess simple <Files> not working

Tags: .htaccess

**Scenario**

I'm simply trying to allow one php file through .htaccess password folder.

**Attempts so far**

- my-special-file.php
- subfolder/my-special-file.php
- ./subfolder/my-special-file.php
- tried using a .htaccess inside the subfolder

**Question**

What am I missing? I know I've gotten little things like this to work before but I'm just not seeing it..

**.htaccess file**

```
AuthUserFile /some/folder/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
Require user personA personB
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All


#not working
<Files "./subfolder/my-special-file.php">
    Allow from All
</Files>

Satisfy Any
```

**Web Page 401**

> ## Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to
> access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong
> credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand
> how to supply the credentials required.
>
> *Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at x.x Port 80*

Comment: Which Apache version are you using?

Comment: @EsaJokinen `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) has changed in Apache 2.4 you are using, and the changes are probably best explained in the [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html). In short, from [mod_access_compat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html):

> Compatibility: Available in Apache HTTP Server 2.3 as a compatibility
>   module with previous versions of Apache httpd 2.x. The directives
>   provided by this module have been deprecated by the new authz
>   refactoring. Please see [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html)

Let's refactor your configuration based on [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) and [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html):

```
<Directory "/var/www/somefolder">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile "/some/folder/.htpasswd"
    Require user personA personB

    <Files "my-special-file.php">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

- The `<Directory>` context can be replaced with `.htaccess`, although [not recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when).
- The `<Files "my-special-file.php">` gets inherited by all the subfolders, i.e.

  - this allows access to `my-special-file.php`, `subfolder/my-special-file.php` etc.
  - If you only want this to be applied to the `subfolder/my-special-file.php`, you'd need:

    ```
    <Directory "/var/www/somefolder">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
        Require user personA personB

        <Directory "/var/www/somefolder/subfolder">
            <Files "my-special-file.php">
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    ```

Comment: Or perhaps use an Apache `<If>` expression to only prompt for a password when `my-special-file.php` is _not_ requested (testing against `REQUEST_FILENAME` or `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` in a server/vhost context, since this is an actual file)? [Something like this](https://serverfault.com/a/975982/49157) from [an earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/975973/htaccess-deny-parent-by-default-allow-single-regex-virtual-subpath).

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, that's possible and worth to mention, but frankly, using `<If>` would be even more confusing to anyone asking this kind of questions on Q/A sites, wouldn't it?